# Rails 3 Rspec 2 problem with :locale and RESTfull path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a problem with `edit_user_path(user)` in my rspec file:

```
it "should forward to the requested page after signin" do
  user = Factory(:user)
  visit edit_user_path(user)

  fill_in :email,    :with => user.email
  fill_in :password, :with => user.password
  click_button

  response.should render_template('users/edit')
end
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: visit edit_user_path(user)
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :locale=>#<User id: 1, name: "Max Mustermann", email: "mel@example.com", encrypted_password: "1b0befc5caf12c2abf53d99sdfsd5ba15ebe28362eae21b2fb3...", salt: "331ca07444f5dcee76605bsdfasd95c833b7d5135b36a253723...", created_at: "2011-02-03 18:54:34", updated_at: "2011-02-03 18:54:34">}
```

I have no clue why it uses the `user` as `:locale` and why there is no `:id` with the `user.id`. I use `:locale` to set the language, e.g. localhost:3000/en/home or localhost:3000/de/home.

This is my `routs.rb`:

```
Hoapp::Application.routes.draw do

scope '(:locale)', :locale => /de|en/  do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :hotels, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  root                      :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/signup',          :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',          :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',         :to => 'sessions#destroy'
  match '/about',           :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/blog',            :to => 'pages#blog'
  match '/contact',         :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/help',            :to => 'pages#help'
  match '/overview',        :to => 'pages#overview'
  match '/preview',         :to => 'pages#preview'
  match '/settings',        :to => 'pages#settings'

  match 'm',                :to => 'mobile#home'
  match 'apartments',       :to => 'mobile#apartments'
  match 'apartment_info',   :to => 'mobile#apartment_info'
  match 'apartment_images', :to => 'mobile#apartment_images'
  match 'apartment_price',  :to => 'mobile#apartment_price'
  match 'wellness',         :to => 'mobile#wellness'
  match 'test',             :to => 'mobile#test'

  scope "m" do
    resources :requests, :only => [:new, :create]
    match 'request_sent', :to => 'requests#sent'
  end

  match ':vanity_url/', :to => "mobile#home"
end
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `url_for` is unable to infer the right parameters when you use a locale? Try it this way:

```
visit edit_user_path(:id=>user.id)
```

Comment: Exactly same issue here. But I'd like not to change my code. Any idea to fix this in the tests?

Comment: worked for me as well, but what do i do when the route is new_user_path? since it doesn't accept any parametes

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found a way to fix this in the tests (cf. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255)

I put this code in spec_helper.rb

```
class ActionView::TestCase 
  class TestController
    def default_url_options
      {:locale => 'en'}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Including this in `spec_helper.rb` worked for me:

```
config.before do
  default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.default_locale
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put this in `config/environments/test.rb` and worked for me:

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = { locale: I18n.locale }`